# serial flash emulation as EEPROM

Tags: c, embedded, flash-memory

I am developing an application on the existing board.
The application  requires frequent data(just 10 bytes) storage,
So I am thinking have the External flash  emulation as EEPROM
because  my board doesn't have the EEPROM.We have the External spi flash is with us.
any one can help me in this emulation or please suggest me the any
other approach to full fill  my application requirement.

Comment: There's no magic involved. Just use one erasable sector for settings. Only difference is that you have to always save all settings at once, because you cannot erase individual bytes.

Comment: I need to store the last used data permanently also.I.e I need to store last used configurations.

Comment: @Muthe That's how flash works unfortunately.

Comment: @Muthe You *can* share user data and program code on same sector, but you need to rewrite that program code always when saving data, *and* make sure that you don't use that specific program section while saving. It is hard to do right, because if save fails, your program is also corrupted.

Comment: @Muthe just a suggestion.  Maybe you can use one whole sector for storage. Just don't erase it every time, you keep writing the data 10 bytes after 10 bytes, and until the whole sector is full, you erase it at once.  It can keep the sector from the erase/write cycle.  However you may need to figure out a flag to separate each 10 bytes you write.

Comment: If you need to write frequently, and your flash is huge compared to your data, consider "walking" across the device using a new sector each time, until you eventually run out and loop back.  Also note you can overwrite bits one way, so you can go back and use that to mark a sector as being superseeded, by changing one byte.

Comment: thanks Chris Stratton.I will try it for single sector and check performance as I am running with Embedded system.

Comment: @user694733 : He won't be running code from an SPI flash device - that is not the issue.

Comment: @ Clifford: Yes you are right.

Comment: @Clifford I didn't notice that. In that case using the whole sector should not be an issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have done the rotating sector before, and it certainly works. Though I would probably use filesystem like [Yaffs](http://www.yaffs.net/) instead for the next project, to have more flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of libraries that can do what you want.  Some years ago i used the Intel library that they provided for their parallel flash chips.

The technique they use is to use additional bytes to designate which value in the flash is valid, and how many bytes the value it occupies.  For example the first time a value is written the valid flag is high.  When the bye is re-written, the valid flag on the old data is set low, and the new value and flag/byte count data is written in the flash immediately after the old value.  When the value is read, you start at the first position, and if the valid flag is low, you use the count to move to where the newer value was stored, and so on until you find a value with the valid flag high.

When an entire sector has been used this way, you need to read the current value, erase the sector, and re-write he current value at the start.

This technique works because a flash bit can be changed form a high to low, but not changed back from a low to a high without erasing.

This explanation is a little simplified, I am sure there will be a tutorial on the web somewhere.